# filter array by its name inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

```
var dictionary = {
  "english" : [{"key" : "1", "value" : "abc"}],
  "french" : [[{"key" : "1", "value" : "xyz"}]]
}
```

if I do this filter it is working  :

```
dictionary.english.filter ( obj => {return obj.value === "abc"})
```

but if mention the array name *english* in a variable and use the same filter it shows me undefined:

```
var language = 'english';
dictionary.language .filter ( obj => {return obj.value === "abc"})
```

what is the difference and how to fix it?

Comment: dictionary[language]

Comment: you can also replace `{return obj.value === "abc"}` with `obj.value === "abc"`. Since it automatically returns. See [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var dictionary = {
  "english": [{
    "key": "1",
    "value": "abc"
  }],
  "french": [
    [{
      "key": "1",
      "value": "xyz"
    }]
  ]
}

var language = 'english';
let _d = dictionary[language].filter(obj => {
  return obj.value === "abc"
})

console.log(_d)
```